# Edit table definition

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

So recently my host upgraded to SQL Server 2012 and so today I wanted to both create a new table and change the datatype of a column in an existing table. However, upon opening the table definition, it looked different than with 2008 and I cannot figure out how to save changes; before I would just make my changes, hit save, and done. Now if I hit save it asks where I want to save .sql file on my computer, there is a new update button that just gives me an error, and there is a window showing t-sql that is creating the table I already have made.

I've only been able to edit using queries, and I really don't want to have to do this all the time, anyone know how to EDIT AND SAVE with SQL Server 2012 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2012?

Below is what I see, don't know if that helps..[Click To View Screenshsot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkmpA.png)

Comment: Have you tried the `ALTER TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements?  You might find the syntax easier than dealing with the user interface.

Comment: That's what I've been doing. To be honest, it's fine, but I prefer the UI, don't have to sit and type it all out...

Comment: Well save the changes to a sql file and see if it's what you would have written if you'd have been more comfortable with raw sql.

Comment: Well what I forgot to mention is that the T-SQL it auto-generates, as you can see in the screenshot, is creating a whole new table when it really should be editing! Why is it doing this? Why isn't it just auto-generating what it needs to so I can just hit the update button and it will work?